# how to get selected option values from multi select box in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I am using multi option selected select box in my angularjs project. But i am not getting all the selected option from the select box. the html code i am using for this is

```
<select class="form-control crm-select-multiple" multiple="multiple" ng-options="option.name for option in cab.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="cab.selectedCab"></select>
```

the angular code to print selected value is

```
var cab = $scope.cab.selectedCab;
console.log(cab);
```

but it is not printing all selected values, printing only one value. so any idea how to print selected value from multi select box.

Answer (score 2):

Your ng-model should be an array for multi-select. Declare it as

Controller:

```
$scope.selectedCab = [];
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control crm-select-multiple" multiple="multiple" ng-options="option.name for option in cab.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="selectedCab"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this fiddle for selecting multiple values

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/6W8Xg/1/

```
   <select ng-options="record.id as record.value for record in records" ng-model="output" multiple="multiple"></select>
```